# Ionic/AngularJS POST request to Django

Tags: angularjs, django, ionic-framework, http-post, django-rest-framework

I have a model "Interview" and a model "Notes". Interview is a foreign key of Notes.

```
class Notes(models.Model):

    notes = models.TextField(null=True)
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.interview
```

I am using http requests to GET and POST to the server.

How can I post notes to the server exactly since interview is a foreign key? Currently my post function looks like this:

```
saveNotes: function(interview, notes) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: apiroute + '/notes',
                data: {
                   "notes": notes, 
                   "interview": {
                       //attr of interview
                    }   

                }
            }).success(callback);
        }
```

And this looks to be correct but I am being met with:

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/api/notes 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

I used "notes/" as my url and I got:

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/api/notes/ 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Can someone give a guess as to what my issue might be?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are my serializer files. Interview is replaced by Lecture

```
class LectureSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lecture
        fields = ('id', 'lecture_no', 'title', 'youtubeLink', 'course', 'keywords')

class NotesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    lecture = LectureSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        fields = ('id', 'notes', 'lecture')
```

[image: What the added data looks like in the admin page]

api views:

```
class LectureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LectureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        course_id = self.request.query_params.get('course',False)
        if course_id:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.filter(course=course_id)
        else:
            lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
        return lectures


class NotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Notes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NotesSerializer
```

Comment: Can you share your api views too ? Why are you using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and not `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: @DhiaTN I followed a tutorial to start up my restAPI that used HyperlinkedModelSerializer, should I not be using it?

Answer (score 1):

you need only to send the `interview_id` value:

```js
data: {
       "notes": notes, 
       "interview_id": interview_id
}
```

and in **serializers.py** define your serializers as follow:

```py
class InterviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
        model = Interview

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     interview = InterviewSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

     class Meta:
        model = Note
```

Comment: I did this and it seemed to work! However, after trying to access the new Interview data with the restapi gui I get this error: 'Interview' object is not iterable. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share you apis method and serializer file?

Comment: I've edited to add the serializer file. I've also realized that although the POST method appears to work and doesn't return an error, it only adds none-values.

Comment: In your case you should use `ModelSerializer` as I mentioned in the example and not `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`. And check the documentation to understand how and when you use HyperlinkedModelSerializer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't. It still doesn't add rows with data, all rows added have None values.

Comment: which field is None? or all fields? If it's adding the rows to the db without error but None, I suppose you have something wrong with your views, or the ajax request data

Comment: All fields are blank. I have posted my views above. Does it look like there's anything wrong with them that you can see?

Comment: in *LectureViewSet* define your `def create(self, request)` function.

Comment: I've made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568799/how-to-post-and-update-using-django
that hopefully can explain the situation a bit better. Thanks!